# How to prevent invisible Firefox requests to RSS feeds linked to pages

Tags: firefox, rss, feed

Firefox browser always requests feeds linked to page and this requests brings garbage to my development serever logs.

It there any way to switch off this annoying requests?

Comment: Yeah, this question has been playing on my mind for long too... whenever I develop with my machine offline (that's the only way to get *anything* done), Firefox makes all these requests and fails, cramming up the error log, which I really *HATE*.

Comment: I remember similar hate from favicon.ico requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a filtered log viewer such as [chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html). That way you can keep all the logs and filter stuff that is not related to your application. You can also turn off firefox RSS feature using ideas similar to those [here](http://userstyles.org/styles/7174). It's just a styling ... I dug and dug the preferences, may be the mozilla default plugin deals with RSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known existing solution. This should be entered as a freature request ("turning this off") in Mozilla Firefox's Bug Tracker.